# how to access a Class form a .rb file created manually in model folder of rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working with a rails-4 application.I have created a couple of models and controllers and everything is fine so far. Now I want to add a **.rb** file in the model folder and that too with out ActiveRecord::Base inheritance and I want to add that class and its members.
I tried the following steps.

```
1) Created a module_access.rb file in model: <br />
2) in that file I have written something as: <br />
   class ModuleAccess
     MODELS = {'Course' => 1, 'BigIdea' => 2, 'LearningOutcome' => 3}
   end
3) I tried the following command in the rails console and it is throwing the follwing error:
    $> ModuleAccess::MODELS
    ERROR: NameError: uninitialized constant ModuleAccess
```

Can any one please suggest me how can I achieve to access this class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module like custom_module.rb and put it in lib and any other folder.
I f you are putting the module in lib then to access through out the application you need to add

```
require_relative '../lib/custom_module'
```

if you are creating any other place then either **include or extend the module in your model class .**